# Second, third best value with same results (VLOOKUP, MATCH...)

Tags: excel

I have a question about LOOKUP/MATCH functions in Excel.
I have a tab with achieved time in column A (for example 01:15:00) and in column B corresponding name of group/person that achieved the time. I already have top 10 times chart (done with SMALL function)

```
=SMALL(A1:A50;1) 2,3,4...
```

and also corresponding group name (Group 1, Group 2...) next to it (with

```
INDEX/MATCH function)
=INDEX(B1:B50;MATCH(SMALL(A1:A50;1);A1:A50;0)))
```

but now I have an issue with three different groups that achieved the same time. Top three groups achieved same time, but the mentioned formula gave me the same group name (Group 1) next to all three results. What can I do when I want to show top times proper way?

PS: I don't want to use filter option in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SMALL again to find the row number of the first row that contains the best time, then index on that:

```
=INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$5=D2,ROW(A$2:A$5)),COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)))
```

but this must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can also do this using the Small function of AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$5)/(A$2:A$5=D2),COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)))
```

which doesn't have to be entered as an array formula.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! Plz accept the answer with a green tick if it answers your question.